# Clock Drift at WSNs

Tags: sensors, omnet++, simulator

Does anyone know how to simulate clock drift on a WSN network using Castalia?
I would like to know if anyone has already done this type of analysis and, if so, what parameters were analyzed and compared.

Answer (score 0):

You can already simulate a very simple model of clock drift in Castalia, by using the `sigmaCPUClockDrift` parameter of the ResourceManager.

There is work by other people who have enhanced Castalia to have more complex clock models. See the following links:

[Work by Thomas Schmid](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.190.9930&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

[Work by Federico Ferrari](https://eudl.eu/doi/10.4108/icst.simutools2010.8693)